# Libgdx I18NBundle, cant show scandinavian letters

Tags: java, internationalization, libgdx, locale

So I've created a I18NBundle for all my strings to support different languages, my problem is that when i draw the strings in my game, the letters æ ø and å wont show, so that something that should be: "Spil på tid" shows up like: "Spil p tid", without the letter.

I don't know what I've done wrong, but you would think that something that is created to support different languages would be able to show the country-specific letters and characters.

Here is my 2 .properties files:

```
infinite_mode=Play Infinite
timed_mode=Play Timed
options=Options
quit=Quit game
option_flip=Flip numpad
option_language=Change language
back=Back to main menu
wrong_number=You pressed the\nwrong number
time_ran_out=Time ran out
reach_50="You have reached 50
score=Score: {0}
time=Time: {0}
numbers_left=Numbers left: {0}
start_over=Start over
leaderboard=Leaderboard
plus_seconds=+{0} seconds!
option_sound=Sound
```

And the danish one:

```
infinite_mode=Spil Evigt
timed_mode=Spil på tid
options=Instillinger
quit=Afslut spil
option_flip=Vend numpad
option_language=Skift sprog
back=Tilbage til hovedmenuen
wrong_number=Du trykkede på\ndet forkerte tal
time_ran_out=Tiden løb ud
reach_50="Du har nået 50
score=Point\: {0}
time=Tid: {0}
numbers_left=Tal tilbage: {0}
start_over=Start forfra
leaderboard=Resultattavle
plus_seconds=+{0} sekunder!
option_sound=Lyd
```

And here is the place where i create the bundle:

```
FileHandle baseFileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("Language/Lang");
        Locale Dansk = new Locale("da", "DK"); //The danish pack
        Locale English = new Locale("en", "GB"); //The English pack

        Lang = I18NBundle.createBundle(baseFileHandle, Dansk);
```

Comment: This is either a file encoding problem or a font problem.  Can you verify with a debugger what actual values the string variable holding the Danish string contains?  Also, what editor do you use to edit the property files?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ to edit the files, and the font is Roboto, which can show the letters if I use normal Strings, just not through the bundle. I'm relatively new to programming, and I'm not too familiar with debugging.

Comment: When I'm debugging the app (don't know if I'm doing it right), under variables if i dig down to the å it shows up like this: �

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue.  If it works using `\u00d8` instead of `ø` it confirms it.  You can then use `\u` for all your Danish characters or ensure that your editor uses the same file encoding as the JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually solved the problem, my self with a lot of help from Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. The problem was in IntelliJ. In settings, the file encoding for '.properties' files were not UTF-8, and by changing that, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful the caractere may not be located/created in the police